# Migrating a Visual Studio C++ Project to Linux and CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm currently trying to move from Windows 10 to Linux (Pop!_OS), but I'm having trouble getting my C++ Project to compile and run correctly on the latter. My C++ project was created using Visual Studio, where I also specified the include folders, library folders, what should be linked, etc in the solution properties. I now want to switch to writing my code using Neovim and not Visual Studio (or Visual Studio Code) and have tried compiling it via G++. I quickly noticed that my include files weren't recognized, so I tried to use CMake and created a CMakeLists.txt. I tried using both

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES()
```

and

```
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES()
```

but no matter what path I enter, my included files were not recognized. Even when I used a path to the specific include file that caused the first error, it still wasn't recognized.

My goal would be that I can specify an include folder and a library folder, so that I can just add files and folders in these and that the new files and folders automatically get recognized when compiling (i.e I would not have to edit the CMakeLists.txt in the future). Is that even possible with CMake and if yes, does anyone know where i can find further information about that or does anyone have a CMakeLists.txt file that does this? If no, would I have to specify each and every file and folder in the CMakeLists.txt file and do the same for every new include and library?

Project structure:

```
Overall folder
\- build
\- include
---> includeFolder1
---> includeFolder2
---> ...
\- libs
---> library1.lib
---> library2.lib
---> ...
\- src
--> main.cpp
--> other .cpp's and .h's
--> other folders with .cpp's and .h's
```

I've tried compiling with G++ and CMake, but both did not work, no matter what I specified as the include and library paths.

Comment: Could you show the `CMakeLists.txt` file? (If it's too large, to be convenient to read, please restrict yourself to 1 target where you could observe this error, preferrably one without dependencies in your own project.) *"Even when I used a path to the specific include file that caused the first error, it still wasn't recognized."* You shouldn't specify files as include directories, but directories... Btw: You could simply create a VS solution via cmake, open it and check, how the include directories differ the cmake-generated solution and your original project.

Comment: *"[...] I can specify an include folder and a library folder, so that I can just add files and folders in these and that the new files and folders automatically get recognized when compiling"* Possible for some generators, but I wouldn't recommend, see the note to [`file(GLOB)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob). After all you'd be adding those files to your VS project too. A reconfiguration after editing a `CMakeLists.txt` file happens anyways...

Comment: Try setting up a CMakeLists.txt for a toy project with one main.cpp and one header file. If you can reproduce the error there, post that *minimal reproducible example*. Otherwise compare what you did differently for the toy example and your proper project.

Comment: @fabian I have updated the post to include the CMakeLists.txt, but I've cut it down a bit for readability. I also added the LINK_DIRECTORIES() command, which should to my knowledge include the library directory, but this line generates an error when running cmake. The include files from the /include/math/ are not recognized. I tried with only the /include/ and with /include/math/ but both didn't work.

Comment: a typo in your repro: `CMAKE_CXX_STANDART` -> `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`. Is that just an error when pasting into your question post, or is that how it actually is in your CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: I'd recommend using `target_link_libraries` instead of `link_directories`.

Comment: @starball you are correct, that was a typo. I have updated the given CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @bitmask That was a good idea, as I now found the error myself using the toy project approach you gave. The error wasn't related to CMake, but it was related to backslashes that I had in my include statements. These worked on Windows, but not on Linux. Thank you.

Comment: @mxHuber You're very welcome. I'm glad it works now. Perhaps you would like to post an answer for future users finding this question?

Comment: @bitmask great idea, I will do this now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem that caused my errors. The problem wasn't with CMake, it was with Windows and Linux specific details. I always received errors like "<foo\foo.h> no such file or directory", which led me to think that CMake couldn't find the include directory or the files in it. The problem, however, is with the include path itself. On Windows, paths can be given with a backslash ('\') but on Linux, paths are denominated with a forward slash ('/'). So in my example, the path to the file was "../foo/foo.h" but my code had "#include <foo\foo.h>". So when migrating a project from Windows to Linux, be sure to watch out for backslashes in your #include statements!

Below is a template CMakeLists.txt, that should be a good starting point if you want to migrate your Visual Studio project to Linux. I've used glfw (+ glad) as an example library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(ExampleProject)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/glad.c src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} GL dl glfw)
```